# opengl texture lod bias adjusting via opengl function call?

Tags: opengl, texture-mapping

how is it possible to change the lod bias via an opengl function call? i dont like the default settings, changes the miplevels too early and makes the nearby ground look ugly.

i couldnt find any codes to do this, every topic was about some external programs that does the job...

Edit: This is my texture settings:

```
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST_MIPMAP_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST_MIPMAP_NEAREST);
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use:

```
glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_FILTER_CONTROL, GL_TEXTURE_LOD_BIAS, bias);
```

More details here:
http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glTexEnv.xml
and there: http://oss.sgi.com/projects/ogl-sample/registry/EXT/texture_lod_bias.txt

EDIT:

Ok, I see. First `GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER` can only take two possible values:

- either `GL_NEAREST`
- or `GL_LINEAR`

So use `GL_LINEAR` for the best result.

Then for `GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER`, with `GL_NEAREST_MIPMAP_NEAREST` you are using no texture interpolation, only mipmaping (you take the nearest mipmap that suits the best, but inside this mipmap you take the nearest texel only, without interpolation between this texel and his neighbours).

So use `GL_NEAREST_MIPMAP_LINEAR` for doing this weighted average between the texels.

With `GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR` you can have even more rendering quality since it will use a linear interpolation between the result of the texture fetch for two mipmaps (mipmap N and N+1) instead of just taking the result of the texture fetch for mipmap N, like previously.

`GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR` is also known as **trilinear filtering**.

Comment: Yep... And the spec is the #1 hit on google with opengl lod bias.